# Overlapping roots across multiple bundles

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I was trying to understand the significance of roots.
As per the docs,

> The roots are not overlapping (e.g., a/b/c and a/b are overlapped and will result in an error.) **Note: This is not enforced across multiple bundles. Only within the same bundle manifest.**

So, I loaded two bundles with same .manifest files with the hope that OPA will not be causing any initialization error based on the above note. But it failed with

```
error: initialization error: detected overlapping roots in bundle manifest with: [/var/folders/hl/7twvsdm52jx6qn3tgkh_4rzm0000gp/T/valid_roots.tar.gz /var/folders/hl/7twvsdm52jx6qn3tgkh_4rzm0000gp/T/duplicate_valid_roots.tar.gz]
```

Am I doing something wrong or have I understood the statement incorrectly or does the document need an update?

**Structure**:

*valid_roots.tar.gz* & *duplicate_valid_roots.tar.gz*

```
./rule
./policy
./.manifest
./policy/policy_1.rego
./rule/rule_1.rego
```

*.manifest*

```
{'roots':['rule/lob','policy/consumers']
```

*OPA run command*

```
opa run -s -a 0.0.0.0:8191 -b /var/folders/hl/7twvsdm52jx6qn3tgkh_4rzm0000gp/T/valid_roots.tar.gz -b /var/folders/hl/7twvsdm52jx6qn3tgkh_4rzm0000gp/T/duplicate_valid_roots.tar.gz
```

Comment: Actually, identifying discrepancy across bundle is good but I just wanted to make sure on the expected behavior.

Comment: Same problem here, but in my case, the overlapping is on the path `system/log`. I'm trying to compose a mask rule between two bundles.

It seems that the documentation is wrong, the overlapping check occurs between bundles too.

Answer (score 2):

*valid_roots.tar.gz* & *duplicate_valid_roots.tar.gz* will be considered as 2 separate bundles and hence you see the `detected overlapping roots` error. If the *valid_roots.tar.gz* has a manifest file with the below content, it means the *valid_roots.tar.gz* owns these roots and no other bundle can write to those paths.

```bash
{'roots':['rule/lob','policy/consumers']
```

The statement you're referring in the docs is the check that is performed while reading a single bundle. If a bundle specifies roots as `a/b/c and a/b`, OPA cannot determine, if the bundle owns everything under `a/b` like `a/b/foo`, `a/b/bar` or it owns only `a/b/c`.